# C# get object that was on top of stack before exception

Tags: c#, exception, stack

I am creating an interpreted programming language in C# (kind of for the lulz, no real purpose other than to have fun and learn about compilers), and ran into a problem. In my lexer, I remember where the token was in the original file to give more useful debug errors. I keep this "TokenPosition" object around, copying it along as the program goes through compile steps, until it winds up in the same object that runs interpreted code (for example, my "Identifier" class for named variables has a TokenPosition member).

My question: If an exception gets thrown, I want to look at the stack, find the topmost object with a TokenPosition member, and print its location. Or, more generally, "How do I get objects that are/were on the stack after an exception? Is this even possible?" (I can do the checking if it has a TokenPosition object / getting it easily, I'm not asking how to do that)

Last resorts that I do not want to have to do: Every single call to a behavior (which happens A LOT) assign a static tokenPosition variable somewhere with this.tokenPosition. I also could surround EVERYTHING with try/catches, but again, I don't really want to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the C# class that the C# method was in when the exception happened, or are you referring to the stack that exists within your interpreter?

Comment: Not restoring the state of your stack when you throw an exception is going to get an interpreter that doesn't work.  Do avoid premature optimization, a try isn't expensive.  Find real bottlenecks with a profiler.

Comment: Jon Hanna, I mean the C# object on the stack. Not the type, I know how to get the type, I need the object that was on the stack (or null if its static, whatever)

Comment: That object might not even exist any more, unless you're doing something to hold onto it and keep it alive. If you're doing something to hold onto it and keep it alive, then use that code to tell you what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters to methods are ephemeral. They may be overwritten by local variables when they are no longer live, or optimized out by the JIT compiler as unused, or even garbage collected [while the method is running](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx). You will have to track this information yourself, for example, by having a separate stack data structure for "currently active object" that is automatically unwound by a `using` clause.

Comment: What would be faster, assignment of static "current location" variable, try/catch, or a using statement? Plus one for the unique idea of using "using". Edit: I just realized, you are talking about methods, I am talking about the class the method is in. The TokenPosition member is inside the class.

Comment: The only way to know is to try it and see. (There are too many unknowns to be able to make a blanket statement about which will be faster / easier to debug / etc.)

Comment: For those of you who might find this question: My probably-flawed testing shows that the try/catch was slower than static assignment on first million, but then was the same for the second for-1-million-loop I did, and sometimes faster. In either case, 1 million try/catches took less than 0.1 seconds, so its not a big performance hit. I did not test the using statement.